# Reading data from serial in python

Tags: python, gps, serial-port, nmea

I got GPS module who returns NMEA data.
When I'm trying to print all data it returns using following code, I'm getting [this](http://s14.postimg.org/6nh9r04u9/output.png).

```
while True:
try:
    rcv = port.read()
    print rcv
```

Then, I've made some modification that will read NMEA data cleaner. It looks like this:

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=10.0)

line = []
print("connected to: " + port.portstr)

while True:
    try:
        rcv = port.read()
    except:
        rcv = ''


    line.append(rcv)

    if rcv == '\n':
        line = "".join(line)        
        print line
        line = []
```

Output looks like that:

> $GPGGA,183345.000,5023.3424,N,01857.3817,E,1,7,1.25,313.3,M,42.1,M,,*53
>
> $GPGSA,A,3,09,26,28,08,15,18,17,,,,,,1.52,1.25,0.88*06
>
> $GPRMC,183345.000,A,5023.3424,N,01857.3817,E,0.40,55.07,050214,,,A*54
>
> $GPVTG,55.07,T,,M,0.40,N,0.74,K,A*0D
>
> $GPGGA,183346.000,5023.3423,N,01857.3817,E,1,7,1.25,313.3,M,42.1,M,,*57
>
> $GPGSA,A,3,09,26,28,08,15,18,17,,,,,,1.52,1.25,0.88*06

The problem is that sometimes it misses some commas or other data, and NMEA parser is reading it wrong. Is there any better and cleaner way to read whole NMEA frames via serial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use readline instead of read, That will continue to read characters until an EOL is received.